# How to close a dialogbox

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created a dialog box in an UiApp, using,

```
 app.createDialogBox();
```

I need to close it after viewing the details and return to the home UI. I did not find any
close button in the dialog box.

I saw a function called, **addCloseHandler()** in the documentation.

Should i use it for closing the dialog, any example or is there any other way?

Sorry if my question is too naive.

Comment: I think the close handler is concerning the inverse process, it fires when the dialog or popup closes - (I'll have to check that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few tests on this it seem there is an [issue 231](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=231&q=dialogbox&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner) and [676 (always classified 'New')](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=676&q=popuppanel&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner) concerning this method but it was open in september 2010 and july 2011 respectively and nothing seems to move...

- [The doc says](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_dialogbox) *A form of popup that has a caption area at the top and can be dragged by the user*, but I cannot make it move... has anyone tried it already ?
- Henrique's suggestion  on autoHideEnabled that is [in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_dialogbox) doesn't seem to be implemented either.

So up to now it seems to be a nice looking panel with a small shadow behind it and very shiny grey caption area that supports HTML... not so bad ;-) but that can just be set (in)Visible. The only major difference with other panels is that its place is kept free even if it's hidden. I used it [in a test app](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbw-3xYzR_kYDAvYUZ99040rCa8urhsTBjBFuYtxlpuCnzKZ3ss/exec) (use *choose a folder* to close / needs authorization on documents & mails, issue 676 has a simple test code)

Comment: Issue 231 is now reported as fixed, 676 as duplicate. Examples provided in 231.

Answer (score 3):

I think dialogs are actually "shown" and "hidden" not actually "opened" and "closed". Following this thought, `setVisible(false)` probably does what you expect. You may also want to take a look on the [setAutoHideEnabled](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_dialogbox#setAutoHideEnabled).

Comment: The nice thing about this forum is that there is always someone to ask for something I didn't think of and -most of the time- someone to bring an answer (sorry for being off topic and thx to both of you)